# Excel file is being corrupted when trying to modify 1 cell using openpyxl python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, vba

I am trying to change 1 cell in a macro enabled excel 2013 file using openpyxl. This should be a relatively easy task I have the following code it works but for some reason when I later try to open the modified  excel file I get the error message from excel.

" We found a problem with some contents in "workbook" do you want to recover?"

if I recover the file it removes a lot of content from the file but I can still see that the only cell I wanted to modify has the correct data.

when I open the error log I get the following message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
<logFileName>error086600_01.xml</logFileName>
<summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\Files\2018 Workflow\Stress Due Date (NA) --- TR9999999 Pckg#9 - Emergency Equipment - 9 - 9 - 9\Panel Analysis --- 9 Version A.xlsm'</summary>
-<repairedParts summary="Following is a list of repairs:">
<repairedPart xml:space="preserve">Repaired Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part. </repairedPart>
 </repairedParts>
 </recoveryLog>
```

The following is my python code, I have looked through the documentation and it seems like it should be working but why is it corrupting my files?

```
""" 
The next part of the script will modify the stress panel excel documents 
"""    
wb = load_workbook(filename = os.path.join(new_path,new_panel + excel_ext), read_only = False, keep_vba = True) 
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Adapter_Panel_Tool")
ws['C2'] = "Adapter Panel Quick Stress Analyses Tool - " +  packet_list['Installations list'][0]
wb.save(os.path.join(new_path,new_panel  + " Version A" + excel_ext))
wb.close()


#checks if there are 2 files: the filled one and the empty one and deletes the empty if it exist. 
is_file_filled_out = os.path.isfile(os.path.join(new_path,new_panel + " Version A" +  excel_ext))
is_there_empty_file = os.path.isfile(os.path.join(new_path, new_panel + excel_ext))
if is_file_filled_out == True and is_there_empty_file == True:
    os.remove(os.path.join(new_path,new_panel + excel_ext))
    print("\n\n The following file will be remove: \n" + new_panel + excel_ext + "\n\n" )
    print("The prefilled template has been created: \n " + new_path + new_panel + excel_ext)
```

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the value of `+ excel_ext`.

Comment: @stovfl excel_ext = ".xlsm"

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce your Issue.